# Array for cycle scalar value warning

Tags: php, arrays, scalar

I have the following function:

```
function define_field($placeholder,&$fields,$val)
{
    $sections=preg_split("/\./",$placeholder);
    if (count($sections)==0)
    {   
    } else if (count($sections)==1)
    {
        $fields[$sections[0]]=$holder;
    } else
    {
        $cur_holder=& $fields;                      
        for($i=0;$i<count($sections)-1;$i++)
        {
            $part=$sections[$i];                
            if (isset($cur_holder[$part]))              
                $cur_holder=& $cur_holder[$part];
            else
            {
                if ($i==0)
                {
                    $fields[$part]=array(array());
                    $cur_holder=& $fields[$part];
                } else
                {
                    $cur_holder[$part]=array(array());
                    $cur_holder=& $cur_holder[$part];
                }
            }
        }
    $cur_holder[$sections[count($sections)-1]]=$holder; 
    }    
}
```

I get this warning:  "Cannot use a scalar value as an array in..."

Here is the warning line:

```
$cur_holder[$sections[count($sections)-1]]=$holder;
```

Does any one knows how to fix this?

Comment: What is the value of `count($sections)`

Comment: You might have a problem with your syntax here `$cur_holder=& $fields;`. `$cur_holder=&$fields;` might fix this.

You can also try declaring `$cur_holder` as an array before using it. `$cur_holder = [];` and then use it.

Comment: @bub the value is 2

Comment: @McRed Already tried to declare $cur_holder in many ways. Do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: ok, I'd var_dump `$sections[1]` and `$cur_holder[$sections[1]]`